# How to fix this errors

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyrogram

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import g4f

app = Client("my_account")

@app.on_message(filters.text & filters.private)
def echo(client, message):
    result = g4f.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        provider=g4f.Provider.ChatBase,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": message.text}],
        stream=False)
    print(result)
    message.reply(result)

app.run()
```

this is userbot errors occur when asking a question:

```
Task \<Task pending name='Task-108' coro=\<Message.reply_text() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\types\\messages_and_media\\message.py:970\> cb=\[\_run_until_complete_cb() at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py:180\]\> got Future \<Future pending cb=\[\_chain_future.\<locals\>.\_call_check_cancel() at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\futures.py:387\]\> attached to a different loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\dispatcher.py", line 242, in handler_worker
await self.loop.run_in_executor(
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\concurrent\\futures\\thread.py", line 58, in run
result = self.fn(\*self.args, \*\*self.kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\Desktop\\PYTHON1\\Python\\UserBot\\Test1.py", line 18, in echo
message.reply(result)
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\types\\messages_and_media\\message.py", line 970, in reply_text
return await self.\_client.send_message(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\messages\\send_message.py", line 126, in send_message
r = await self.invoke(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\methods\\advanced\\invoke.py", line 79, in invoke
r = await self.session.invoke(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\session\\session.py", line 389, in invoke
return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\session\\session.py", line 326, in send
payload = await self.loop.run_in_executor(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Task \<Task pending name='Task-108' coro=\<Message.reply_text() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\types\\messages_and_media\\message.py:970\> cb=\[\_run_until_complete_cb() at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\base_events.py:180\]\> got Future \<Future pending cb=\[\_chain_future.\<locals\>.\_call_check_cancel() at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\futures.py:387\]\> attached to a different loop
```

It was supposed to be a userbot that should answer questions in Telegram. But errors occur,
At first I made it asynchronous, but there were even more incomprehensible errors, here is the asynchronous code:

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import g4f

app = Client("my_account")


@app.on_message(filters.text & filters.private)
async def echo(client, message):
    result = g4f.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        provider=g4f.Provider.ChatBase,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": message.text}],
        stream=False)
    print(result)
    await message.reply(result)


app.run()
```

And errors:

```
Exception in callback Task.task_wakeup(\<Future finished result=None\>)
handle: \<Handle Task.task_wakeup(\<Future finished result=None\>)\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\events.py", line 80, in \_run
self.\_context.run(self.\_callback, \*self.\_args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task \<Task pending name='Task-37' coro=\<Dispatcher.handler_worker() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\dispatcher.py:204\> wait_for=\<Future finished result=None\>\> while another task \<Task pending name='Task-36' coro=\<Dispatcher.handler_worker() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\dispatcher.py:240\>\> is being executed.
Exception in callback Task.task_wakeup(\<Future finished result=None\>)
handle: \<Handle Task.task_wakeup(\<Future finished result=None\>)\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\events.py", line 80, in \_run
self.\_context.run(self.\_callback, \*self.\_args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task \<Task pending name='Task-19' coro=\<Session.ping_worker() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\session\\session.py:276\> wait_for=\<Future finished result=None\>\> while another task \<Task pending name='Task-36' coro=\<Dispatcher.handler_worker() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\dispatcher.py:240\>\> is being executed.
Exception in callback Task.task_wakeup(\<Future finished result=None\>)
handle: \<Handle Task.task_wakeup(\<Future finished result=None\>)\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\events.py", line 80, in \_run
self.\_context.run(self.\_callback, \*self.\_args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task \<Task pending name='Task-4' coro=\<Session.recv_worker() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\session\\session.py:297\> wait_for=\<Future finished result=None\>\> while another task \<Task pending name='Task-36' coro=\<Dispatcher.handler_worker() running at C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyrogram\\dispatcher.py:240\>\> is being executed.
```

Comment: There are a lot of spurious backslashes here, though most of them can clearly be ignored. Perhaps it would still be good to clean this up. In very brief, on the desktop version of this site, paste your code or traceback, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

Answer (score 0):

`g4f.ChatCompletion.create_async`
This solved my problem